# What happens when local / Session Storage is full?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, chrome-web-store

I know its near to impossible but I have a question in my mind.

what will be the behavior of the web application if all the web storage(local / session) is full in angular web app ?

Does it effect the performance of the web app ? if yes then how it will effect ?

how the application will react in the following browsers chrome, firefox and Opera ?

I'm reading a blog which discuss the session and local storage but i did't find my Answer there.
(https://krishankantsinghal.medium.com/local-storage-vs-session-storage-vs-cookie-22655ff75a8)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If storage is full when you try to add something to it, according to [the specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/webstorage/#storage-0) the method that's adding the new/updated item must throw a `QuotaExceededError`. So your app/page will work just fine if storage is full but if it tries to add anything, that action will fail with an error.

From that link:

> The `setItem(key, value)` method must first check if a key/value pair with the given *key* already exists in the list associated with the object.
>
> If it does not, then a new key/value pair must be added to the list, with the given *key* and with its value set to *value*.
>
> If the given *key* does exist in the list, and its value is not equal to *value*, then it must have its value updated to *value*. If its previous value is equal to *value*, then the method must do nothing.
>
> **If it couldn't set the new value, the method must throw a `QuotaExceededError` exception. (Setting could fail if, e.g., the user has disabled storage for the site, or if the quota has been exceeded.)**

*(my emphasis)*

Comment: its mean the current behavior of the application will not change until you update/add something. and when you try to add/update then it will throw QuotaExceededError .

Comment: @WaheedKhan - Right, unless of course the application code handles the error in some way.

Answer (score 1):

There is a special exception for that: quota exceeded.
You can read about it here: https://chrisberkhout.com/blog/localstorage-errors/